# AJax does not seem to work on the delete button

Tags: django, ajax

I am really new to ajax. I want to delete the entry from database on button click and I do not want the page to reload. but the ajax doesn't seem to work at all. What is wrong in my code? Please suggest the correct code. Thanks in advance.

```
 <script>

$(document).on('click','#delete',function(){
 var a ;
 a=confirm("Do you really want to delete the user?");
if(a==true){
 var newurl = "{% url 'NewApp:centredelete' pk=1%}"
 var id = $(this).attr('name')
 $.ajax(
{
    type:"GET",
    url: "newurl.replace('1',id);",
    data:{
             delete:True
    },
    success: function( data )
    {
        if(data.success == true){
            $(id).remove();
         }
         else{
            alert(data.error)
         }
     }
     })}
});
</script>
```

views.py

```
def CentreDeleteView(request, pk):
    centre = Centre.objects.get(pk=pk)
    centre.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('NewApp:centrelist'))
```

edit:
urls.py

```
url(r'^centredelete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.CentreDeleteView,name='centredelete'),
```

I am getting "Not Found: /NewApp/centrelist/url.replace('1',id);
" in the terminal. I don't know why it is taking the wrong url.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly add your url file here and mention here the response on server terminal

Comment: I don't know why I am getting Not Found: /NewApp/centrelist/url.replace('1',id);
this in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

**replace "newurl.replace('1',id);" with newurl.replace('1',id)** in your ajax.
You've used double quotes around newurl.replace('1',id) so the url will send as is instead of replacing '1' with the required id.